# reference material for attributes of <a> and <img> tags

Tags: javascript

I am troubleshooting this line of code: e is of type image(img) and b is of type link(a).  It seems to be concatenating the local host to e.src and not doing just a direct copy of the string.

Where is reference material located on the Mozilla Development Network that lists object properties, particularly the .src property of my image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign a proper `href` attribute if you want to extract the `hostname`.

Instead of:

```
<a href="www.ay.com">link</a>
```

you should do:

```
<a href="http://www.ay.com">link</a>
```

or at least:

```
<a href="//www.ay.com">link</a>
```

Then you'll be able to extract the hostname. Otherwise the browser assumes `www.ay.com` is a local file or directory.

---

If for some reason you can't change the `href`, then you'll need to use `getAttribute()` to be able to retrieve it unmodified.

```
e.src=b.getAttribute('href');
```

Comment: ha, thanks that's what I was looking for href property, I can just access it using .href correct?  It should be referenced somewhere https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SVG/Element/a#Attributes

Comment: @Chris: [This page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_DOM_Reference) has a list of links to DOM element Interfaces, which will contain information about element properties. It also gives corresponding links to the DOM Element pages which will give attribute information.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not totally mistaken, that's a property of HTML links. If you have `<a href="www.ay.com">` the link will point to `http://example.com/www.ay.com`. In this case you probably want `e.src = b.href`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your link is wrong. Use http://www.ay.com instead.

Answer (score 0):

MDN Documentation refers to object properties as attributes, the relevant documentation for the attribute 'href' for the 'a' element is found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTML/Element/A)